# ¿Por qué me tira el mensaje "the assigned value is never used" en unas variables sí las estoy usando en un if?

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Estaba siguiendo el código que vi en un video de YouTube y lo escribí tal cual estaba en el video, sin embargo, me marca que no he usado las variables de tipo String que declaré al inicio pero sí las estoy usando. Ya traté de cambiar y declararlas directamente en la parte en la que se ingresa la información a través de un Scanner pero aunque deja de marcar el error cuando ejecuto el código no corre.

```
package cadenasdecaracteres;

import java.util.Scanner;  

public class CadenasDeCaracteres {

    public static void main (String[] args){
    
        String nombreUno = "", nombreDos = "";
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Por favor, ingrese el primer nombre: ");
        nombreUno = entrada.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Por favor, ingrese el segundo nombre: ");
        nombreDos = entrada.nextLine();
        
        
        if(nombreUno.equals(nombreDos)){
        
            System.out.println("Los nombres son iguales.");
        } 
        else{
        
            System.out.println("Los nombres son diferentes.");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje se debe a que las variables nombreUno y nombreDos las inicializas con con un valor vacío y nunca se hace nada con ese valor.
Debido a que en las siguientes lineas se les asigna un valor (leído desde la consola con la clase Scanner), las variables podrían dejarse sin  inicializar.
`String nombreUno, nombreDos;`

Sin embargo, si estas comenzando a aprender, puedes ignorar la alerta ya que no afecta en nada. A medida que vaya avanzando si es importante prestar atención a eso detalles para tener mejor rendimiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

No hay ningún error en el código, el mensaje de advertencia `the assigned value is never used`, significa que estas asignado un valor a esa variable pero no lo estas usando en ninguna operación y el IDE te está informando que esa variable se puede eliminar y no afectar lo que realiza el programa.